# Azure App Service JSON Transform using KeyVault

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-keyvault, azure-appservice

I am looking at deploying a .Net Core WebApi service to an Azure App Service and as part of the deployment I am keen to update the connection string in the `appsettings.json` with the CosmosDb connection string.  I have a Azure KeyVault which has the connection string stored in there as a secret.

Using the YAML build pipeline for CI/CD I have the following (snippet) from my pipeline

```
          - task: AzureKeyVault@1
            inputs:
              azureSubscription: '<service-principal>'
              KeyVaultName: '<keyvault-name>'
              SecretsFilter: '*'
              RunAsPreJob: true
          
          - task: AzureRmWebAppDeployment@4
            inputs:
              ConnectionType: 'AzureRM'
              azureSubscription: '<service-principal>'
              appType: 'webApp'
              WebAppName: '<ci-resource-group>'
              VirtualApplication: '/'
              packageForLinux: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/**/*.zip'
              JSONFiles: '**/appsettings.json'
```

These two tasks are in a stage which starts with downloading the published artifact from a previous stage.

So the Azure App Service Deploy task can do JSON transformation but I need to define a variable in the format `ConnectionStrings:CosmosDb` with the value from the secret stored in the keyvault and that I am not certain of how to do!

- Firstly, is this the correct way? I have seen articles about using a reference to the secret in the keyvault, is that the correct way?
- The keyvault secrets are available to the pipeline using `$(secret)`, how can I create a variable for the `AzureRmWebAppDeployment@4` task as above?

Everything I have found so far points to the Classic release pipelines, and using variable groups but this needs to be part of the YAML pipeline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/transforms-variable-substitution?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#jsonvarsubs)

> To substitute values in nested levels of the file, concatenate the names with a period (.) in hierarchical order.

But your secrets cannot have dots in name so you must do a small rewrite between those two steps:

```
- powershell: |
     echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=ConnectionStrings.CosmosDb;]$(ConnectionStrings-CosmosDb)"
```

where your secret is `ConnectionStrings-CosmosDb`