# How to externalize configuration - azure pipelines?

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

We all know how to have separate config files per environment in Asp.Net Core. However, i am looking for a solution for my usecases below:

The Asp.Net core application should read its config entries from a file named appsettings.json which is present in the web app directory. We will not have environment specific json files but one file that will dynamically populated with the environment specific configuration during the release pipeline and just before deployment.

This file will be checked in to the repository so it should not define any values but only the keys

When the release pipeline runs, the appsettings.json file should be populated with the values before deployment and thus become a valid configuration source.

Is there a way i can store environment specific configuration in the pipeline such that it serves as the input source of the release pipeline and helps to populate the appsettings.json file later in the pipeline and just before deployment?

thanks in advance!!

Comment: You should use an Azure-native configuration management solution such as app settings or Azure App Configuration. Don't rely on configuration files, rely on your cloud provider to inject appropriate configuration settings into your application via environment variables or via the application knowing how to query and retrieve them at runtime.

Comment: Hi friend, any update for this issue? Please check if answer below helps to resolve your question. Feel free to let us know if you're still blocked :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible. You can configure your pipeline into stages and then use different variable group just to this specific stage:

[image]

You can go even further and keep your secret in Azure Key Vault and just link specific Key Vault with variable group.

To fill your config you can use [json substitution](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/transforms-variable-substitution?view=azure-devops&tabs=Classic#jsonvarsubs) if you use App Services. Please check also this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63630797/azure-app-service-json-transform-using-keyvault/63631373#63631373). (If not you may be forced to use [Replace Token](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=qetza.replacetokens) extension)

But as Daniel mentioned check [App Configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-app-configuration/overview) to get all benefit of being in the cloud.